# AngularJs - What is the best way to display buttons dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularJs. Can someone point me the easy and best way to display links dynamically from angularJs to html.

I want to display "n" (n>=0) buttons in html dynamically where i get value of 'n' from db. Suppose if n is 5, 5 buttons should be displayed when i load html page and Also i want to know which button user clicked.

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by using "ng-repeat" directive.

Try the code below:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <button ng-repeat="n in getArray(number)" id="button-{{$index}}" ng-click="getButtonClicked($index)" >This button repeats times</button>
</div>
```

Script:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app',[]);
        myApp.controller('AppCtrl' , function($scope){
            $scope.number = 5;
            $scope.getArray = function(num){
                var array = [];
                for(var i = 0 ; i < num;i++){
                    array[i] = i +1;
                }
                return array;
            }
            $scope.getButtonClicked = function(buttonNumber){
                alert(buttonNumber + 1 + " is clicked");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

view:

```
<button ng-repeat="n in getNumber(number) track by $index" 
        ng-click="pressed(n)">
            This button repeats n times
</button>
```

controller

```
$scope.number = 5; // MyService.getN();

// ng-repeat only accepts collection as parameter
$scope.getNumber = function (num) {
    return new Array(num);
}

$scope.pressed = function(num) {
    alert("Pressed button " + num);
}
```

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6o2fo2fj/5/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from devqon is completely correct, but in case you would be using Angular 1.3, it would be better not to use the $scope for this but instead use the 'Controller as vm' syntax. Basically the code is completely the same as the above answer but just written based on best practices.

```
   app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
        var amountOfButtons = 5;
        this.buttons= new Array(amountOfButtons);
        this.handleButtonClick = handleButtonClick;

     function handleButtonClick(index){
       console.log('Clicked: ' + index);
     }
   });

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
       <button ng-repeat="button in vm.buttons track by $index" ng-click='vm.handleButtonClick($index)'>button {{::$index}}</button>
</body>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ofi5Ra7fgg1OsmPLe1sb)

Comment: Could you enlighten me with the statement "in case you would be using Angular 1.3, it would be better not to use the $scope for this but instead use the 'Controller as vm' syntax"? :)

Comment: In Angular 2.0 there won't be a $scope anymore, this controller as syntax will be the way to go. More information (and other reasons why to use the controller as syntax) can be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController (see Example section)

Answer (score 0):

use ng-repeat in your code which is the best and the easiest way..just look for my fiddle example..much easier..
You will be as follows..

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-repeat="button in buttons(number) track by $index" ng-click="click($index+1)">Button</button>
</div>
```

and your angular script is simple as follows..

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.number = 5;//predefined amount of buttons

    // ng-repeat only accepts collection as parameter
    $scope.buttons = function (noOfButtons) {
        return new Array(noOfButtons);
    }

    //this will trigger when clicked a button
    $scope.click = function(buttonNo) {
        alert("Clicked button " + buttonNo);
        //button number is tracked by $index
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sanjayastn/pcggeag9/